# Not returning successful form validation rules

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why my form validation run function is returning false. According to the docs it says the following:

> The run() function only returns TRUE if it has successfully applied your rules without any of them failing.

Here's what my rules look like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nicknames', 'Nicknames',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hometown', 'Hometown',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('height', 'Height',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Weight', 'Weight',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('manager', 'Manager',
        'required|integer');   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('setup', 'Setup',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('finisher', 'Finisher',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('biography', 'Biography',
        'required');
```

Here's what the post submission runs:

```
biography   Kid coming out of college getting the chance of a lifetime.
finisher    Idolizer
height  5'4"
hometown    Las Vegas, Nevada
manager 0
nicknames   "The Quintessential Cruiserweight of KOW!"; "K-Dub"
setup   That's Wondeful
submit  Submit
weight  140 lbs.

http://pastebin.com/F9XeEibf

function biographySubmit()
{
    $outputArray = array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'unproccessed');
    $outputMsg = '';
    // Sets validation rules for the login form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nicknames', 'Nicknames',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hometown', 'Hometown',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('height', 'Height',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Weight', 'Weight',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('manager', 'Manager',
        'required|integer');   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('setup', 'Setup',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('finisher', 'Finisher',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('biography', 'Biography',
        'required');   

    // Checks to see if login form was submitted properly(
    if (!$this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $outputArray['message'] =
            'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!';
    }
    else
    {
        $bioFields = array($this->input->post('nicknames'), $this->input->post('hometown'), $this->input->post('height'), $this->input->post('weight'), $this->input->post('manager'), $this->input->post('setup'), $this->input->post('finisher'), $this->input->post('biography'));          
        if ($this->bios->updateBiography($bioFields, $this->session->userdata('defaultRosterListID')))
        {
            $outputArray = array('success' => 'Yes', 'message' =>
                                        'Biography were updated successfully!');
        }
        else
        {
            $outputArray['message'] =
            'The biopgraphy was not able to be updated in the database. Please try again later!';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($outputArray);
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
var validateform = $("#biographyForm").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
            ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted.'
            : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted.';
            $('.box #biographyForm .content').removeAlertBoxes();
            $('.box #biographyForm .content').alertBox(message, {type: 'warning', icon: true, noMargin: false});
            $('.box #biographyForm .content .alert').css({
                margin: '0',
                borderLeft: 'none',
                borderRight: 'none',
                borderRadius: 0
            }).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
        } else {
            $('.box #biographyForm .content').removeAlertBoxes();
        }
    },
    ignore : 'input:hidden:not(:checkbox):not(:radio)',
    showErrors : function(errorMap, errorList) {
                    this.defaultShowErrors();
                    var self = this;
                    $.each(errorList, function() {
                        var $input = $(this.element);
                        var $label = $input.parent().find('label.error').hide();
                        if (!$label.length) {
                            $label = $input.parent().parent().find('label.error');
                        }
                        if($input.is(':not(:checkbox):not(:radio):not(select):not([type=file])')) {
                            $label.addClass('red');
                            $label.css('width', '');
                            $input.trigger('labeled');
                        }
                        $label.fadeIn();
                    });
                },
    errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
                    if(element.is(':not(:checkbox):not(:radio):not(select):not([type=file])')) {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    } else if(element.is('select')) {
                        error.appendTo(element.parent());
                    } else if (element.is('[type=file]')){
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    } else {
                        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
                    }

                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        error.wrap('<div class="error-wrap" />');
                    }
                },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var dataString = $('#biographyForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'biography/biographySubmit',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $('.box #biographyForm .content').removeAlertBoxes();
                    $('.box #biographyForm .content').alertBox(data.message, {type: 'warning', icon: true, noMargin: false});
                    $('.box #biographyForm .content .alert').css({
                        width: '',
                        margin: '0',
                        borderLeft: 'none',
                        borderRight: 'none',
                        borderRadius: 0
                    }).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.box #biographyForm .content').removeAlertBoxes();
                    $('.box #biographyForm .content').alertBox(data.message, {type: 'success', icon: true, noMargin: false});
                    $('.box #biographyForm .content .alert').css({
                        width: '',
                        margin: '0',
                        borderLeft: 'none',
                        borderRight: 'none',
                        borderRadius: 0
                    }).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 'slow' );   
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Posting the relevant HTML code of the form might be helpful here.

Comment: Is hard to tell.. just a guess try to enter height without a single quote, write 5.4 instead of 5'4

Comment: I updated my post with the html form

Comment: please post the code in the controller.

Comment: so which field does it say is failing validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will totally fix your problem but your form doesn't seem to have an `action`. It should be something like `action="[your site url]/your_controller_name/biographySubmit"`.

You could use CodeIgniter's URL Helper and use this: `action="<?php echo site_url("your_controller_name/biographySubmit"); ?>"`

Without an action, the data in the form won't be passed to the `biographySubmit` function within your controller.

Comment: That's not it because I'm validating the form with jquery and using athe ajax function to send to php.

Comment: @user1333299 Could you post the relevant jQuery and ajax code? Do you know which validation check(s) is failing? If you put this in your view: `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` it will show which checks aren't being passed, when you submit.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Have you tried adding `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` to your view? Does it show any errors?

Comment: It seems really odd to me that the `run()` function is returning false and `validation_error()` isn't returning anything. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with jQuery, so I'm not sure if anything wrong is there. Could you not just use CodeIgniter's validation on it's own, without the jQuery validation?

Comment: well i prefer to validate on both ends so a client side validation is required and I prefer jQuery.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure about the jQuery code, as I'm not too familiar with it- but it looks ok to me. I'm still confused as to why `run()` is returning false and `validation_errors()` isn't showing any errors. Sorry, it's hard to tell given what I can see.